# Angular 4 : rendering different with input type color in a form or not

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jhipster

I'm working on an app built with JHipster and Angular 4.3. I've a problem with the use of input type color in an angular form. I need a color picker to change a color attribute. First I just displayed values of a list (ctrlColors) and a color picker, it was OK. But the users need to customize the colors, so I made a form. 
Now when I load my page, I don't have all the colors displayed, but only the last of the list (screen below)

I've followed this simple example : [input type color example with Angular](https://codepen.io/davidsturgeon/pen/lIgEG)
And I built my form with Angular.io documentation and [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/angular-forms/).

I've a model ControlColor.model.ts like this :

```
export class ControlColor implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public color?: string,
        public control?: Control,
    ) {
    }
}
```

In an other component I have this in MyComponent.html :

```
<form #ctrlColorForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitColors(ctrlColorForm.form);">
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let ctrl of ctrlColors">
            <td>{{ctrl.control}} :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="color"
                       [(ngModel)]="ctrl.color"
                       #nameField="ngModel"
                       name="color"
                       (ngValue)="ctrl.color"
                style="color-rendering: {{ctrl.color}}"/>
            </td>
            <td>{{ctrl.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
        <span class="d-none d-md-inline" jhiTranslate="entity.action.edit">Edit</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

The strange part is that when I remove the `<form>` balise, the rendering is Ok (I have the right colors sent from my server and I can edit the colors), but when I put the form balise, I have this :

[image: display problem with input type color in form balise]

I have the right RGB codes (displayed on the right).
Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that all input elements have the same name (`name="color"`). According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#how-to-use):

> When using the ngModel within `<form>` tags, you'll also need to supply
>   a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent
>   form under that name.

If you make the input control names different, the color will be displayed correctly in each one, as shown in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-b2531l):

```
<tr *ngFor="let ctrl of ctrlColors; let i=index">
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="color" [(ngModel)]="ctrl.color" name="color_{{i}}" ... />
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```